# Active Color in Pageview builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-test, dart-pub

I want to make the centre widget border colour Basic widget should be have active colour when i slide it Silver widget will be centre so Silver widget should be active then to purple.

[image]

while slider the centre widget border colour must be active constantly.what should I do?

I'm not getting the logic how to make it as active colour

Answer (score 0):

at start you must create a contoller for you page view
after that you check current pageIndex from your controller with the index in pageBuilder
if they are same then your condition ......

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood you want to change border color of the widget containing the plan [Image With Marked Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbJ0e.png) to purple if clicked on the specific plan.

If so,

1. Store index

store the current index selected in the widget state and change the color accordingly.

eg in decoration the **color** property will have condition:

```
color: currIndex==planIndex?Colors.purple:Colors.black,
```

where **currIndex** is the index currently selected and **planIndex** is index of the plan in list (basic:0,silver:1,etc)

2. Add onPageChanged callback.
   like so:

```
onPageChanged:(i)=> setState(()=>currIndex=i),
```